# RestFul web service which reads properties file

Tags: java, rest

I have got couple of Jersey REST Web services say **SendPassword** and **ResetPassword** whose purpose is to send email .

For sending email , i have configured a properties file under tomcat and all this works fine

The code of the `SendPassword.java` is somewhat this way

```
 @Path("/sendpassword")
    public class SendPassword {
        @GET
        @Produces("application/json")
        public String sendPasswordToEmail(@QueryParam("empid") String empid)
                throws JSONException
        {
            try {

            SendEmailUtility.sendmail("weqw","2312");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
}
```

**SendEmailUtility.java**

```
public class SendEmailUtility 
    {
    public static String sendmail(String sendemalto,String generatedpwd) throws IOException {
        String result = "fail";
        File configDir = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "conf");
        File configFile = new File(configDir, "email.properties");
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(configFile);
        Properties props_load = new Properties();
        props_load.load(stream);
        final String username = props_load.getProperty("username");
        final String password = props_load.getProperty("password");
        Properties props_send = new Properties();
        props_send.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        props_send.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
                        Transport.send(message);
          // Some code to send email
            result = "success";
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            result = "fail";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

***As you can see i am reading the properties file for every call of the websercice***

(As reading operation is somewhat costly) , Is there any way to resolve this ??

Could you please let me know whats the best approach to handle this.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: There're multiple ways. You can eliminate the static, or use singleton pattern and read the properties in constructor, finally you can initialize the properties in a static block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to do this the one way of doing it is to make the props_load a private static member of the class and call it like this

```
    public class SendEmailUtility 
    {
       private static Properties props;

      private static Properties getProperties() {
       if (props == null) {
        File configDir = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "conf");
        File configFile = new File(configDir, "email.properties");
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(configFile);
        props = new Properties();
        props.load(stream);
    }
    return props; 
    }
    public static String sendmail(String sendemalto,String generatedpwd) throws  IOException {
        String result = "fail";
        Properties props_load = getProperties();
        final String username = props_load.getProperty("username");
        final String password = props_load.getProperty("password");
        Properties props_send = new Properties();
        props_send.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        props_send.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
                Transport.send(message);
          // Some code to send email
            result = "success";
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            result = "fail";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

The other design I would suggest is to make an email service class like EmailSender or EmailService and then inject it into SendPassword class

```
@Path("/sendpassword")
    public class SendPassword {
        @Autowired
        EmailService emailService;
        @GET
        @Produces("application/json")
        public String sendPasswordToEmail(@QueryParam("empid") String empid)
                throws JSONException
        {
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using resource bundle, which does not need InputStream

create a properties file and put directly inside your packages along with your java code

example folder structure

```
com
   - preethi
            -SendPassword.java
            -email.properties
```

Then you can code like

```
ResourceBundle props_load = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.preethi.email");
final String username = props_load.getString("username");
```

This way you don't have to worry about opening and closing the stream or file path

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lazy-getter to fetch and cache the `Properties` object.

```
private static Properties props;

private static Properties getProperties() {
    if (props == null) {
        File configDir = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "conf");
        File configFile = new File(configDir, "email.properties");
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(configFile);
        props = new Properties();
        props.load(stream);
    }
    return props;
}
```

Each time you want to use the Properties, call `getProperties()`. It will cache it the first time it's called. Each subsequent call will just return the cached object.

Note: This example does not catch any exceptions.